# Need to convert to lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x

i try to write this function to lambda function,I tried a lot of options and I could not success:

```
 def getitem_rlist(s, i):
    while i > 0:    
      s, i = rest(s), i - 1
    return first(s)
```

I know to begin with:

```
getitem_rlist=lambda s,i:....?
```

thanks!
in to example if: `s=(1,(2,(3,4)))` then  `getitem_rlist(a,2))# -> 3`
the function need to return the element at index i of recursive list s

Comment: what is first and rest ... this looks like you are trying to squish lisp into python ....

Comment: yes,I write it right now, in to example if: s=(1,(2,(3,4))) print(getitem_rlist(a,2)) -> print 3

Answer (score 2):

```
getitem_rlist=lambda s,i: getitem_rlist(s[1:][0],i-1) if i > 0 else s[0]
```

maybe what you want ....  Its hard to tell withpout knowing what those other methods do  ...

```
>>> getitem_rlist=lambda s,i: getitem_rlist(s[1:][0],i-1) if i > 0 else s[0]
>>> s=(1,(2,(3,4)))
>>> getitem_rlist(s,2)
3
```

Comment: i try to write it but it dosent work,the function need to return the element at index i of recursive list s

Comment: now it does ... i didnt understand what rest was ... I think i fixed it ... it works at least for the s you listed as example

Comment: i got this error: TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: it might be a problem with your rest or first so I got rid of them also posted example of it working ... if you are using a different s that may be the problem ... all I had was the s you gave in example